# Delete database record by using window scheduler

Tags: database, batch-file, window, delete-file

I created an auto-backup task using windows scheduler to backup my database by using .bat.

Inside my backup folder got 7 sub-folder (monday, tuesday, wednesday...) to keep the daily backup database.

How to delete the last week's db and keep the latest version? For example, today is thursday, I want to delete last thursday's db and keep today's db?

Here is .bat command?

```
sqlcmd -S NATE-PC\SQLEXPRESS2008R2 -U user1 -P user -i C:\scheduled\schedule.sql

del d:\Backup\db_backup_*.bak ?? what should I write here
```

Here is the sql query in order to run daily

```
   DECLARE @pathName NVARCHAR(512) 
SET @pathName = 'D:\Backup\db_backup\' + DATENAME(DW,GETDATE())+'\'+ Convert(varchar(8), GETDATE(), 112) + '.bak' 
BACKUP DATABASE [LEWREDB] TO  DISK = @pathName WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'db_backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for deleting command

```
forfiles /p "d:\Backup" /m "db_backup_*.bak" /c "cmd /c Del @path " /d -7
```

[Here this the description](http://www.ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)